# display detail page based on id?

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple items coming from database, and I would like to see the details when I click on some of them based on the id.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                            ?>
                                <a href="./pages/detail.php&id=<?php echo $row["id"] ?>"  class="home-card">
                                    <img src="upload/img/<?php echo $row["image"] ?>" alt="<?php echo $row["title"] ?>" class="mb-10">
                                    <div class="home-card__content">
                                        <h3 class="mb-10"><?php echo $row["title"] ?></h3>
                                        <h4 class="mb-10"><?php echo $row["artist"] ?> <?php echo $row["vocal"] ?></h4>
                                        <h4><?php echo $row["label"] ?></h4>
                                    </div>
                                </a>
```

So, I have the correct url when I clicked on an item:

> /pages/detail.php&id=2  --> this one doesn't work

But, I have a 404 Not Found when I click on any of these items:
`The requested URL was not found on this server.`

However if I only redirect to the detail page without the &id= the page is loading correctly

```
<a href="./pages/detail.php"  class="home-card">
```

> /pages/detail.php --> this one works

Here's what I use in detail.php page:

```
if(isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = $_GET["id"];

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT m.id,m.artist, m.title, m.label, m.image, m.vocal, m.audio, m.created_at, g.name AS genre
                       FROM music m LEFT JOIN genre g
                       ON m.genre_id = g.id
                       WHERE m.id = :id");
                       
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $id);

    $stmt->execute();

}

// Html code to display detail
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Maybe you don't have a `./pages/detail.php`, at least not relative to whatever page your link is on.

Comment: What is the *complete* URL for the working example, and for the non-working example?

Comment: I have that page in the correct folder, the detail page is displayed if there isn't any id in the url

Comment: localhost/custom-playlist/pages/detail.php works but localhost/custom-playlist/pages/detail.php&id=2 doesn't work

Comment: @stylaxxx: Time to do some debugging then.  Is any of the PHP code in `detail.php` executing at all?  If you replace it all with nothing but `echo "test";` what happens?  If control is never even reaching the code on that page, your next step is web server logs or any other overarching system which would be handling the request before it reaches the PHP code, to see where this 404 response is coming from.

Comment: "test" is displayed on the page if I remove &id= from the url (/pages/detail.php), so the basic detail page. If a had the id, no matter what I write in detail.php, I have a 404 not found.